# Magento set customer address as default address in address book page itself

Tags: magento-1.9, customer, billing-address

How can I set address as default billing address when a radio button is added in customer address book without going to edit address page. Please find the below screenshot,

https://prnt.sc/ihngmf

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you open **app/code/core/Mage/Customer/controllers/AddressController.php**
You can see following code

```
$address->setCustomerId($customer->getId())
    ->setIsDefaultBilling($this->getRequest()->getParam('default_billing', false))
    ->setIsDefaultShipping($this->getRequest()->getParam('default_shipping', false));
```

So in your case

```
$address->setCustomerId($customer->getId())
    ->setIsDefaultBilling($addressId)
    ->setIsDefaultShipping($addressId);
$address->save();
```

**[Update]**

Pass **id** as address_id and your controller code should be following:

```
$customer = Mage::getSingleton('customer/session')->getCustomer();
/* @var $address Mage_Customer_Model_Address */
$address  = Mage::getModel('customer/address');
$addressId = $this->getRequest()->getParam('id');
if ($addressId) {
    $existsAddress = $customer->getAddressById($addressId);
    if ($existsAddress->getId() && $existsAddress->getCustomerId() == $customer->getId()) {
        $address = $existsAddress;
    }
}

if(!$address->getId()) {
    return;
}

$address->setCustomerId($customer->getId())
    ->setIsDefaultBilling($addressId)
    ->setIsDefaultShipping($addressId);
$address->save();
```

Comment: thanks @sohel in the code how can i check radio button?

Comment: You can use by ajax for save them and for checked radio button use simple if-else logic like if($customer->->getDefaultBilling() == $addressId) { checked}.

Comment: so it should be like---- new Ajax.Request('<?php echo $this->getUrl("customer/address/formpost")?>', {------

Comment: formpost action require more field-value combination. If you pass all of them then yes. or create your own.

Comment: i have created another controller and little bit confused how to set exactly

Comment: I mean the how exactly the clicked address will be set as default billing and shipping address in the new controller?

Comment: Check updated answer

Comment: @SohelRana do you know how to set one of existing address as default billing and shipping without adding new one, Thank You